# Terraform - Azure How to create B2C identity provider

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following `terraform` code to create an `azure` - `azurerm_aadb2c_directory` as below:

```
resource "azurerm_aadb2c_directory" "example" {
  country_code            = var.b2c_country_code
  data_residency_location = var.b2c_data_residency_location
  display_name            = var.b2c_display_name
  domain_name             = "${var.b2c_display_name}.onmicrosoft.com"
  resource_group_name     = var.b2c_rg_name
  sku_name                = var.b2c_sku
}
```

And Now I want to create one of the Identity Providers (as mentioned in the below screenshot) But I can't find the `terraform` resource for that.

Can someone help me find the right `terraform` resource and how to modify/create/customize the page as show in the below screen snip?

[image]

Comment: If you want to create User flows with the AzureAd B2C provider, Unfortunately it is not possible, Refer the possible terraform configurations for Azure AD B2C here - https://codez.deedx.cz/posts/automating-azure-ad-b2c-creation-with-terraform/

Comment: only the settings mentioned here are available for aad b2c terraform resource provider - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_identity_provider_aadb2c and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/aadb2c_directory but you can call the identity provider with azure APIM terraform resource provider, Refer here - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/aadb2c_directory

Answer (score 1):

By default Azure Terraform Resource provider does not contain configurations to set the Identity Provider for Azure AD B2C.

```
resource "azurerm_aadb2c_directory" "example" {
  country_code            = "US"
  data_residency_location = "United States"
  display_name            = "example-b2c-tenant"
  domain_name             = "exampleb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"
  resource_group_name     = "example-rg"
  sku_name                = "PremiumP1"
}
```

Output:-

[image]

[image]

And other provider is for getting the properties of the existing Azure AD B2C tenant.

```
data "azurerm_aadb2c_directory" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "example-rg"
  domain_name         = "exampleb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com"
}

output "tenant_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_aadb2c_directory.example.tenant_id
}
```

Output:-

[image]

> I also tried checking Microsoft Rest API to update IDP in AAD B2C via
> terraform, But there’s no API call to create or update IDP in azure AD
> B2C.

But **You can call a Rest API to update the password credentials of an App in your Azure AD B2C** with social IDP or local IDP by using the code below:-

Created one google developer IDP and got the client ID and Client secret from the registered app:-

[image]

```
terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm  =  {

source = "hashicorp/azurerm"

version = "3.47.0"

}

}

}

  
  

provider  "azurerm" {

features {}

subscription_id  =  "<subscription-id>"

}

  

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "appgrp" {

name  =  "app-grp"

location  =  "West Europe"

}

  

resource  "null_resource"  "configure_social_idp" {

provisioner  "local-exec" {

command  =  <<EOF

set AZURE_TENANT_ID="<tenant-id>"

set AZURE_CLIENT_ID="<client-id>"

set AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="<client-secret>"

set AZURE_AD_B2C_APP_ID="<app-id>"

  
  

curl -X POST \

-H "Authorization: Bearer $(az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.windows.net | jq -r .accessToken)" \

-H "Content-Type: application/json" \

-d '{

"keyCredential": {

"customKeyIdentifier": null,

"displayName": "Google",

"endDateTime": null,

"key": null,

"startDateTime": null,

"type": "Symmetric",

"usage": "Verify",

"value": "<idp-password>"

},

"passwordCredential": null,

"publicClient": null,

"replyUrls": [],

"requiredResourceAccess": [],

"web": null

}' \

"https://graph.windows.net/\<tenant-id>/applications/\<object-id>/addKeyCredential?api-version=1.6"

EOF

}

}
```

Output:-

[image]

[image]

References:-

[Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/aadb2c_directory)

[azurerm_aadb2c_directory | Data Sources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/aadb2c_directory)

[B2C Tenants - Create - REST API (Azure Azure AD B2C) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants/create?tabs=HTTP)

[B2C Tenants - Update - REST API (Azure Azure AD B2C) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants/update?tabs=HTTP)